Adaptation of an esp-idf code to arduino language
I am having problems adapting an esp-idf code (esp32 native language) to Arduino language, based on a github code (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/system/freertos/real_time_stats/main/real_time_stats_example_main.c), it gives me an error when equating the malloc () function with a variable of the TaskStatus_t type, which is done in the original github code (written in esp32-idf, line 62) and I do not know how to adapt that code to Arduino language. Code that I am adapting to the Arduino language:
  TaskStatus_t *startArray = NULL;
  TaskStatus_t *endArray = NULL;
  UBaseType_t startArraySize;
  UBaseType_t endArraySize;
  
  startArraySize = uxTaskGetNumberOfTasks() + 5;
  startArray = malloc(sizeof(TaskStatus_t) * startArraySize);

PS: I don't know anything about esp-idf that's why I'm asking

it gives me an error when equating the malloc () function with a variable of the TaskStatus_t type -- what error are you getting exactly? When you say TaskStatus_t type I assume you mean TaskStatus_t * type

@miron The function malloc in Arduino is of void type but in ESP-IDF it returns TaskStatus_t and I don't know what function is equivalent in Arduino language.

malloc always returns void * even in ESP-IDF. It's a standard C library function. What error message are you getting?

The error I get is the following error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'TaskStatus_t* {aka xTASK_STATUS*}' [-fpermissive]

Normally in C, one does not typecast malloc return. In this case, I'm not sure what compiler you are using. If it's a C++ compiler, it may give the error, so you could try typecasting: startArray = (TaskStatus_t *)malloc(sizeof(TaskStatus_t) * startArraySize);.
